# Iterativelly combine strings and remove the first strings

Tags: python

For a given string I want to make groups two by two, but when the first group is created I want to delete the first letter and then group those.
Like this:
Initial string: `'ACGT'` Goal: `['AC','CG','GT']`

So I did this code:

```
for i in range(0, len(seq_example), n):
    out = [seq_example[i:i + n(len(seq_example) - 1)]]
```

However, there is one missing combination. Can somemone help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to your problem in Python.

I Used your code and change some things and I think that now it should work well.

```html
seq_example ='ACGT'

out =[]
for i in range(len(seq_example)-1):
    out.append(seq_example[i:i+2])

print(out)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do:

```
seq_example = "ACGT"
window = 2
out = [seq_example[i:i+window] for i in range(len(seq_example)-window + 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple indexing will do the job

```py
s = 'ACGT'
[s[i:i+2] for i in range(len(s)-1)]
```

```
['AC', 'CG', 'GT']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
seq_example = list('ACGT')
li = list(map("".join, zip(seq_example, seq_example[1:])))
```

---

**li:**

```
['AC', 'CG', 'GT']
```